# problem with python pillow, not really sure what's wrong

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

> So we're basically supposed to be making boxes looking like this with pillow:
> [enter image description here]
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/has57.png)
> The boxes should be forming randomly.

```
def draw_quilt():
  width = 400
  height = 400
  grid_size = width / 4

  img = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))
  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

  r = 0; g = 192; b = 192
  for higher_y in range(0, height, grid_size):
    lower_y = higher_y-grid_size
    r += 10; g-= 10; b-= 10 
    for higher_x in range(0,width, grid_size):
      lower_x = higher_x+grid_size
      draw_patches(draw, int(grid_size / randomint(1,3), top_x, top_y, bottom_x, bottom_y, (r, g, b))

def draw_patches(draw, patch_width, start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y, color):
  r = color[0]; g = color[1]; b = color[2]
  for top_y in range(start_y, end_y, patch_width):
    r += 10; g += 5; b += 3
    bottom_y = top_y + patch_width
    for top_x in range(start_x, end_x, patch_width):
      r += 10; g += 5; b += 3
      bottom_x = top_x + patch_width
      draw.rectangle((top_x, top_y, bottom_x, bottom_y), fill = (r, g, b))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    img  = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    
    draw_quilt()

    img.save('question4.png')
    img.show()
```

> I'm not really sure about what's wrong, but it just keeps appearing "Syntax Error" on the screen

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing `)` at the end of this line:

```
draw_patches(draw, int(grid_size / randomint(1,3), top_x, top_y, bottom_x, bottom_y, (r, g, b))
```

The `SyntaxError` you're getting is on the line that contains `def draw_patches` but the actual error is the line before.

Comment: @sj95162 changed the code a little bit, there's no error now, but it's not drawing anything (I've put the new code below)

Answer (score 0):

```
def draw_quilt():
  width = 400
  height = 400
  grid_size = int(width / 4)

  img = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))
  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

  r = 150; g = 299; b = 299
  for top_y in range(0, height, grid_size):
    r += 10; g += 5; b += 3
    bottom_y = top_y + grid_size
    for top_x in range(0, width, grid_size):
      r += 10; g += 5; b += 3
      bottom_x = top_x + grid_size
      draw_patches(draw, int(grid_size // randint(1,3)), top_x, top_y, bottom_x, bottom_y, (r, g, b))

def draw_patches(draw, patch_width, start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y, color):
  r = color[0]; g = color[1]; b = color[2]
  for top_y in range(start_y, end_y, patch_width):
    r += 10; g += 5; b += 3
    bottom_y = top_y + patch_width
    for top_x in range(start_x, end_x, patch_width):
      r += 10; g += 5; b += 3
      bottom_x = top_x + patch_width
      draw.rectangle((top_x, top_y, bottom_x, bottom_y), fill = (r, g, b))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    img  = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    
    draw_quilt()

    img.save('question4.png')
    img.show()
```